# Tika - omitting specific mime-type

Tags: mime-types, apache-tika

Is there a way to configure Tika to ommit one of default mime type? Considering I don't want use custom tika-mimetypes.xml

I have tried following configuration file but the excluded mime is still being used.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<properties>
    <parsers>
        <parser class="org.apache.tika.parser.DefaultParser">
            <mime-exclude>message/rfc822</mime-exclude>
        </parser>
        <parser class="org.apache.tika.parser.EmptyParser">
            <mime>message/rfc822</mime>
        </parser>
    </parsers>
    <detectors>
        <detector class="org.apache.tika.detect.DefaultDetector">
            <mime-exclude>message/rfc822</mime-exclude>    
        </detector>
    </detectors>
</properties>
```

Comment: What do you want to omit the type for - detection, parsing, both?

Comment: detecting only, I tried both just to make sure

Comment: Short answer - no. Why would you want Tika to not tell you about a type it can correctly identify?